# Bulk collect and forall with dynamic query

Tags: plsql

```
Declare
    Vquery varchar2(32000);
    Vitem varchar2(50);
    Vskuloc varchar2(50);
    vstartdate Date;
    Vdur Number;
    vtype Number;
    vqty Float(126);
    GP_ohpost Date:= fnc_ohpost;
    sdate1 Date:= to_date('01/01/1970','dd/mm/yyyy');

    Cursor C_DRIVER is
        (Select h.*,b.item,b.skuloc,h.rowid
         FROM SCPOMGR.histwide h, SCPOMGR.dfutosku b
         WHERE  h.dmdunit=b.dmdunit
         AND  h.loc=b.dfuloc
         AND (b.eff = Sdate1 OR b.eff <= h.startdate
         AND b.disc = Sdate1 OR b.disc > h.startdate)
         And NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SCPOMGR.SKUHIST d
                 WHERE b.dmdunit = d.item
                 AND   b.skuloc =  d.loc
                 AND   h.startdate = d.startdate
        )) order by h.StartDate;
    TYPE GP_cursor_Type IS TABLE OF C_DRIVER%ROWTYPE;
    GP_cursor_tab GP_cursor_Type := GP_cursor_type();
    c_limit constant PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10;
    TYPE GP_Insert_type IS TABLE OF scpomgr.skuhist%ROWTYPE; 
    GP_Insert_tab GP_Insert_type := GP_Insert_type(); 
    GP_tot_accept_fetched NUMBER := 0;
begin    
    OPEN C_DRIVER;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_driver BULK COLLECT INTO GP_cursor_tab limit c_limit;
        Exit when c_driver%NOTFOUND;
        FOR i IN GP_cursor_tab.FIRST .. GP_cursor_tab.LAST LOOP
        vquery:= 'Select ...<skipped to make post shortest>';
        Execute immediate vquery BULK COLLECT INTO GP_Insert_tab;
        FORALL i IN INDICES OF GP_Insert_tab
            Insert into scpomgr.skuhist 
             values( GP_Insert_tab(i).startdate
                              ,1
                              ,10080
                              ,GP_Insert_tab(i).qty
                              ,GP_Insert_tab(i).item
                              ,GP_Insert_tab(i).loc
        );
        End Loop;
    End Loop;       
    Close C_DRIVER;
END; 
/
```

What i want to do here is i want to use the forall query outside of loop but if i am using the forall with the 2 nd array outside the loop then.all of the records are not getting inserted to the final table..please suggest me some solution....

Comment: this needs formatting

Comment: The thing is, you've obfuscated the most important part of the code: `vquery:= 'Select ...<skipped to make post shortest>';`. If you hide the query which populates the array - and which is presumably dependent on some data from the outer loop - there isn't much we can do to offer alternate implementations. Perhaps you could just explain the business rules you're trying to code? Ii's usually better than expecting us to reverse engineer them from a chunk of PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Ankita.
I didn't know the structure of your tables, so i made a simple tables to understand what should work here:

```
create table histwide (f1 number);
insert into histwide values (1);
insert into histwide values (2);

create table skuhist (f1 number);

select * from histwide
select * from skuhist
```

Now i changed your code keeping changed code in comments. Seems it works. I think the trouble was because of you are used `Exit when c_driver%NOTFOUND;` in begining of loop. It is wrong for `FORALL` because after first fetching cursor is empty (if limit is reached).
So, my solution of your case:

```
Declare
    Vquery varchar2(32000);
    Vitem varchar2(50);
    Vskuloc varchar2(50);
    vstartdate Date;
    Vdur Number;
    vtype Number;
    vqty Float(126);
    GP_ohpost Date:= trunc(sysdate); --fnc_ohpost;
    sdate1 Date:= to_date('01/01/1970','dd/mm/yyyy');

    Cursor C_DRIVER is
                        (Select h.*--,b.item,b.skuloc,h.rowid
                                    --FROM SCPOMGR.histwide h, SCPOMGR.dfutosku b
                           FROM histwide h
                                    /*WHERE  h.dmdunit=b.dmdunit
                                                AND  h.loc=b.dfuloc
                                                AND (b.eff = Sdate1 OR b.eff <= h.startdate
                                                AND b.disc = Sdate1 OR b.disc > h.startdate)
                                    And NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SCPOMGR.SKUHIST d
                                    WHERE b.dmdunit = d.item
                                    AND   b.skuloc =  d.loc
                                    AND   h.startdate = d.startdate
                                    )) order by h.StartDate*/
                           );
    TYPE GP_cursor_Type IS TABLE OF C_DRIVER%ROWTYPE;
    GP_cursor_tab GP_cursor_Type := GP_cursor_type();
    c_limit constant PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10;
    TYPE GP_Insert_type IS TABLE OF skuhist%ROWTYPE; --scpomgr.skuhist%ROWTYPE; 
    GP_Insert_tab GP_Insert_type := GP_Insert_type(); 
    GP_tot_accept_fetched NUMBER := 0;
begin
    OPEN C_DRIVER;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_driver BULK COLLECT INTO GP_cursor_tab limit c_limit;


        Exit when GP_cursor_tab.count = 0;
      dbms_output.put_line('arr cur size: '||GP_cursor_tab.count);

        FOR i IN GP_cursor_tab.FIRST .. GP_cursor_tab.LAST LOOP

            vquery:= 'Select * from histwide';
            Execute immediate vquery BULK COLLECT INTO GP_Insert_tab;
         dbms_output.put_line('arr size: '||GP_Insert_tab.count);

--          FORALL j IN INDICES OF GP_Insert_tab
                FORALL j in GP_Insert_tab.first..GP_Insert_tab.last --works too
                Insert into skuhist --scpomgr.skuhist 
                values(GP_Insert_tab(j).f1
                         /*GP_Insert_tab(i).startdate
                        ,1
                        ,10080
                        ,GP_Insert_tab(i).qty
                        ,GP_Insert_tab(i).item
                        ,GP_Insert_tab(i).loc*/
                        );
        End Loop;

        Exit when c_driver%NOTFOUND; --it should be at end of the loop.

    End Loop;
    Close C_DRIVER;
END; 
/
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...but i want is there any way to use the forall outside the loop and get all the records inserted in to the table.

Comment: then just fetch all records into `GP_cursor_tab ` with no limit and not in loop. It will allow you to take all records in array and you will manage to remove main loop. `Fetch` command can be used not in loop